# Emacs regular freezes: How to identify cause?

Tags: emacs, profiler

I'm having regular freezes in Emacs (every 15 Seconds and then for 2 to 3 Seconds).

I stated the Profiler with CPU:

```
- ...                                                            4588  44%
   Automatic GC                                                  4588  44%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                                3405  33%
+ command-execute                                                1887  18%
+ timer-event-handler                                             384   3%
+ flyspell-post-command-hook                                       18   0%
+ undo-auto--add-boundary                                           8   0%
+ internal-echo-keystrokes-prefix                                   8   0%
+ delete-selection-pre-hook                                         7   0%
+ eldoc-schedule-timer                                              3   0%
  tooltip-hide                                                      3   0%
  internal-timer-start-idle                                         2   0%
+ gui-set-selection                                                 2   0%
+ global-visual-line-mode-check-buffers                             1   0%
+ deactivate-mark                                                   1   0%
```

How can i proceed from here to identify the root cause.
This kind of freeze is annoying when typing longer code or text.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version of `emacs`? Did you try a newer one (like [Emacs 26.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html) in august 2018) ?

Comment: I would first eliminate the mode-line and header-line as potential time-consuming things that get evaluated during `redisplay_internal` and are difficult to spot using the built-in profiler.  After you have turned off all mode-lines and header-lines (in all buffers -- for all frames), then repeat the profiling process.  Also, click the plus sign for `redisplay_internal` and `command-execute` so that we know what you are dealing with there.  Garbage collection is generally a necessary evil, and can cause a noticeable pause; e.g., when holding down the arrow-key and moving left/right rapidly.

Comment: It's very unusual for garbage collection to be dominating the CPU time like that.  I can't suggest what it is, but it sounds like you have some code which is continually generating a lot of garbage, so isolating that is probably your main goal.  If GC is also causing 2-3 second delays, then that also sounds unusual to me -- I wouldn't expect a GC run to take as long as that. Have you messed with `gc-cons-threshold` or `gc-cons-percentage`?

Comment: Regarding things happening periodically, I can see `flyspell` in your backtrace, so I would disable that completely to establish whether it's connected with your problem.